# Alternative to setCredentialStore method for google analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

I am using the following code for Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data.

```
private Analytics iniAnalytics (String secureFolder) {
        try {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            JsonFactory jasonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
                                    jasonFactory, 
                                    new FileReader(secureFolder + "client_secrets.json"));
            FileCredentialStore credentialStore = new FileCredentialStore(
                    new File(secureFolder, "analytics.json"), 
                    jasonFactory);

            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                                    httpTransport, 
                                    jasonFactory, 
                                    clientSecrets,
                                    Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY))

                        .setCredentialStore(credentialStore).build();
            Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver())
                                    .authorize("user");

            return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, jasonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("myapp/Analytics/2.0").build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What alternative code for above as method setCredentialStore get deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

adding from previous answer:

If you want to specify the filename, you can use `DataStore<StoredCredential> dataStore = dataStoreFactory.getDataStore("specificFilename");`,then in `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` use the `.setCredentialDataStore(dataStore)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FileDataStoreFactory fdsf = new FileDataStoreFactory(String whereToSave)` and then in your `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` use the `.setDataStoreFactory(fdsf)` method.

Any subsequent launch this method will automatically check the location you specified for the storedCredential file and use that to give you the Credential you want.