# Specific filename for FileDataStoreFactory (Google API)

Tags: java, google-api

Previously, if we were using `FileCredentialStore`, we are able to specific the stored filename for Credential information.

However, `FileCredentialStore` is depreciated

[Alternative to setCredentialStore method for google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144375/alternative-to-setcredentialstore-method-for-google-analytics)

Now, we are using `FileDataStoreFactory`.

However, there is no way for us to specific saved filename anymore. We can only specific directory name. The filename will be fixed to **StoredCredential**

Is there any way I can specific filename? As I have different credential information, and I would like to group them within single directory.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory("/path/to/dir");
DataStore<StoredCredential> dataStore = dataStoreFactory.getDataStore("specificFilename");
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
   httpTransport,JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
   .setCredentialDataStore(dataStore).build();
```